# Aren't 'latitude' and 'longitude' tags redundant?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't see any point in using both of this tags. In most cases they are used simultaneously when the topic involves coordinates in lat/lon. Not only latitude AND longitude are always involved simultaneously (I haven't seen any question where only one of this tags could be applied and not both of them) - so it would be more appropriate to use tag named 'lat/lon' or something like that; but the common sense tells us that these questions are about coordinates and actually there is nothing special in latitude or longitude and we already have the 'coordinates' tag.

I believe that these two tags should be deleted because they provide no help at all and 'coordinates' tag is already there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having looked at the questions tagged [latitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latitude) & [longitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longitude), I whole heartedly agree that the current usage of these tags on most of these questions (there are [89 question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longitude+latitude) currently tagged with both) is unhelpful, and the tags should be removed from these questions. In most questions, these tags could be replaced by the new [lat-long](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lat-long) tag.

However, I wouldn't recommend that we delete these tags or ban their individual usage. There can be many instances where the correct usage of individual tags would be useful, helpful and valid.

- Suppose I want to ask 'Which projection would I use in high latitude areas (beyond the Arctic circle)?' The latitude tag would be valid.
- Questions like [How to find the most east or west longitude around the date line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66323) & [Longitudinal extent of Asia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69414) and others dealing with the International Date Line could be tagged with longitude

So overall I'll say that we edit the wiki on the tags, and recommend that [lat-long](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lat-long) be used in most cases, and the individual tag be used in only specific cases.

Comment: +1 I have created a `lat-lon` tag and made it the target synonym both for the `latitude` and `longitude` tags. I also inspected the tag wikis before doing this and created a new wiki for the new tag that combined the information from the synonyms. Creating synonyms does not change any of the original tagging on the questions. The two biggest effects are (1) `lat-lon` will appear as the auto-completion of "lati" or "longi" when typing in a tag and (2) [searching for the latitude tag or the longitude tag](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lat-lon) will find threads with *either.*

Comment: Because "coordinates" is a far broader concept than either latitude or longitude, I do not recommend conflating the `coordinates` tag with the new `lat-lon` tag.

Comment: <strike>I confess to being surprised there are so many tagged with lat & long. I've not noticed them because, to me, they're a pointless tag. They should be made synonyms of lat-long.</strike> whups, @whuber dealt with it already. :)

Comment: Consider 'Geographic Coordinates' as an additional tag that identifies latitude/longitude.  'Projected Coordinates' could be used for all the planar (XY) coordinate systems.